# Convert $x^2+y^2+z^2=49$ to spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates

I really need your help to convert this $x^2+y^2+z^2=49$ to spherical coordinates.

I tried it and I got $(R\sin\phi\cos\theta)^2+(R\sin\phi\sin\theta)^2+(R\cos\phi)^2=49$.

But it says that it is wrong, or I have to simplify it. And I don't know if I am on the right track or not.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, just a little bit further simplification gives you: $R = 7$.

Comment: Square, then ask yourself what you can do with the first 2 terms; after some simplification, what can you do with the simplified term and the other one?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation). I have edited your post. Please check whether you are satisfied with the changes and edit post further, if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equation of a sphere, so you can write immediately that
$$R^2=49,$$
since $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$.

But you could get to this the way you started, simply by repeatedly using
$\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ to simplify your final expression.

$$(R\sin\phi\cos\theta)^2+(R\sin\phi\sin\theta)^2+(R\cos\phi)^2=
R^2\sin^2\phi(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)+R^2\cos^2\phi =
R^2\sin^2\phi+R^2\cos^2\phi =
R^2(\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi)= R^2$$

Comment: OMG thanks mate. that all makes since